# Parsing spring import statement inside custom tag

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-bean

I have a Java application that parses an xml file of the following format.

```
<x:foo xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:x="http://www.hello.org/x/foo"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hello.org/x/foo http://schemas.hello.org/x/foo-1.0.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">

    <x:myBeans>
        <bean id="my-bean-1" class="org.hello.sample.SampleClass1">
            <!-- some properties goes here -->
        </bean>
        <bean id="my-bean-2" class="org.hello.sample.SampleClass2">
            <!-- some properties goes here -->
        </bean>

        <import resource="sub-file.xml"/>
    </x:myBeans>

    <x:otherElements>
        <!-- Some non-spring xml elements (which are not used by application logic) goes here -->
    </x:otherElements>
</x:flow>
```

The **myBeans** tag contains a set of native spring beans and import statements. The **otherElements** tag contains a set of elements that are only used by a separate application which generates this file. My application is **only interested in those spring beans and imports**.

So I'm using the following custom bean parser to parse this file and add the spring bean definitions to the spring context.

```
public class MyBeanDefinitionParser extends AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser {

    @Override
    protected void doParse(Element element, ParserContext parserContext, BeanDefinitionBuilder builder) {
        Element myBeansElement = DomUtils.getChildElementByTagName(element, "myBeans");
        if (myBeansElement != null) {

            // Parsing 'bean' elements
            List<Element> beanElements = DomUtils.getChildElementsByTagName(myBeansElement, "bean");
            for (Element beanElement : beanElements) {
                BeanDefinitionHolder bdh = parserContext.getDelegate().parseBeanDefinitionElement(beanElement);
                parserContext.getRegistry().registerBeanDefinition(bdh.getBeanName(), bdh.getBeanDefinition());
            }

            // Parsing 'import' statements
            List<Element> importElements = DomUtils.getChildElementsByTagName(myBeansElement, "import");
            for (Element importElement : importElements) {
                // TODO   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The parsing and adding spring beans (my-bean-1, my-bean-2) to the context works fine. 
But how can I parse and add the beans defined in the file **sub-file.xml** (which has the same structure) to the spring context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the above working as follows.

```
// Parsing 'import' statements
List<Element> importElements = DomUtils.getChildElementsByTagName(myBeansElement, "import");
Resource currentResource = parserContext.getReaderContext().getResource();
for (Element importElement : importElements) {
    String importPath = importElement.getAttribute("resource");
    try {
        Resource importResource = currentResource.createRelative(importPath);
        parserContext.getReaderContext().getReader().loadBeanDefinitions(importResource);
    } catch (IOException | BeanDefinitionStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Also I had to parse the import statements before the bean elements, so that the bean refs are not broken.